# The api request gets the correct answer via postman, but the curl request in the server side receives a null response

Tags: php, json, api, postman

Here are the 3 parts of my code:

- Part "a" is my curl request body.
- Part "b" is my website backend that includes a curl request.
- Part "c" is the result of this request in postman.

I don't get any error but I receive a null response. Could you please tell me what is the problem that I receive a null response in my browser?

part a:----------------------------------

```
class API
{

    /**
    * @var string
     */

    private $ip = "http://localhost:5000";

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $baseUrl = "/M-Pages/Api";
    private $port;
    private $method;
    private $header;
    private $body;
    private $rout;
    private $curl;

    /**
     * API constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->curl = curl_init();
    }

    /**
     * @param $rout
     * @param $method
     * @param null $port
     * @param array $header
     * @param array $body
     */
    public function curlRequest($rout , $method = null , $port = null,$header = ["content-type: application/json"] , $body = [])
    {


        // set parameter of request
        $this->initRequestParameters($rout, $method, $port, $header, $body);

        // set option of request
        $this->initCurlOptions();

        // execute curl request and get result
        $response = curl_exec($this->curl);

        // get error of curl request
        $err = curl_error($this->curl);

        // close curl

        // check error of request
        if ($err) {
            //TODO :error change

            echo "CURL Error #:" . $err;//TODO: set custom error function
        } else {
            return $response;
            curl_close($this->curl);
       }
    }

    /**
     * @param $rout
     * @param $method
     * @param null $port
     * @param array $header
     * @param array $body
     */
    private function initRequestParameters($rout , $method , $port = null, $header = ["content-type: application/json"] , $body = []){

        $this->port = $port != null ? $port : "5000";
//        var_dump( $this->port );
        $this->method = $method != null ? strtoupper($method) : "GET";
//        var_dump( $this->method);
        $this->header = $header != [] ? $header :["content-type: application/json"];
//        var_dump($this->header);
        $this->body = $body != [] ? $body : [];
//        var_dump($this->body);
        $this->rout = $rout;
//        var_dump( $this->rout);
    }

    /**
     * @return resource
     */
    private function initCurlOptions()
    {

        switch ($this->method) {
            case "POST":
                $this->initPostRequestOption();
                break;
            case "GET":
                $this->initGetRequestOption();
                break;
        }

        return $this->curl;

    }

    private function initPostRequestOption()
    {

        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, array(CURLOPT_PORT => $this->port,
                CURLOPT_URL => $this->ip . $this->port . $this->baseUrl . $this->rout,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $this->method,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $this->header)
        );

//        var_dump( $this->ip . $this->port . $this->baseUrl . $this->rout);

    }
   private function initGetRequestOption()
    {
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, array(CURLOPT_PORT => $this->port,
                CURLOPT_URL => $this->ip . $this->port . $this->baseUrl . $this->rout,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $this->method,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $this->header)
        );
    }

} 
part b:----------------------------
 $body = "{\n \"params\" : {\"user_name\":\"".$user_name . "\"}}";
//                var_dump($body);
                $this->api = \DI::mapClass("API", "API", $GLOBALS["namespace"]["service"]);
//                echo 'api FIRST';
                $res = $this->api->curlRequest("/First/login","POST",[],[], $body);
                $res = json_decode($res, true);
                var_dump($res);
                exit();
```

part c:----this is my postman environment and response of my request:

[image]

Comment: What is `$res` _before_ the `json_decode`? If `json_decode` can't decode, it returns null.

Comment: $res is $response of curl request .that is null ,but why?it work in postman and whole of step is true.mr. @JonStirling

Comment: You override `$res` See `$res = $this->api->curlRequest("/First/login","POST",[],[], $body); $res = json_decode($res, true);` So which are you saying is null?

Comment: Both of them are null @JonStirling

Comment: A long shot, but I've had browser extensions/plug-ins that ate my json/xml data and showed null. Maybe try monitoring via devtools, trying another vanilla browser or disabling all extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP guy so this answer might be totally wrong, but it seems like you are mapping a service to a particular API with `$this->api = \DI::mapClass("API", "API", $GLOBALS["namespace"]["service"]);` I understand you have the class API, but in the postman you are sending the POST to *Api*/First/login (notice the capitalization) which is also reflected in your code. Could that be a typo that's making your curl request come up null? Should that line read `$this->api = \DI::mapClass("API", "Api", $GLOBALS["namespace"]["service"]);`?

Comment: this line _$this->api = \DI::mapClass("API", "Api", $GLOBALS["namespace"]["service"])_ is equal  whit ($this->api=new Api();),after that api class is built ,Call method  **curlRequest** and pass parameter to it. @Davenporten

Comment: Should curlRequest return something? @Fatima

Comment: yes it should return **{
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "doc_fname": "فاطمه",
        "doc_lname": "ترکی",
        "doc_pass": "$2a$10$f4e828d7376550ef12aa0u6p2/Yo0Lh91zeNHJa56ZwCykuQPbwTG"
    }**  but response in browser is null !!!! @Davenporten

Comment: I mean the actual function. You have a return statement in the else of the if($err) but nothing if it is an error. You might just be missing the echo, but try returning the $err and seeing what you get. @Fatima